# Approximate long-term sliding averages in Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I want to compute a sliding average with the window size of a week using Apache Spark Streaming. Results should be delivered timely, i.e. with sub-minute latency. Storing a week's worth of streaming data is impractical in my case though this would be required to compute exact results (please correct me if I am wrong).

Thus, I aim for some kind of approximation. My idea was to use a 1h tumbling window to produce a stream of 1h pre-avg results `s_1`. Then I would use a sliding average with the duration of one week on `s_1` to compute 1 week pre-avg results `s_2`. Apart from `s_1` and `s_2` I would have another stream `s_3` that contains sliding average results over 1h. I would then join streams `s_2` and `s_3` and for join tuples `(t_2, t_3)` I would emit `(t_2 + t_3) / 2`. To every average tuple I would also attach the min and max timestamps of the included tuples. I would use these timestamps to prevent overlapping of s_2 and s_3 tuples. For example:

```
s_2 tumbling window size 2 (tuples)
s_3 sliding window size 2, interval 1 (tuples)
stream 3  4  9  8  7     

time    s_2    2_3    out
1        -      3      3
2        -     3.5    3.5
3       3.5    6.5    3.5   the s_3 tuple 6.5 is ignored because  min_timestamp(6.5) <= max_timestamp(3.5)
4       3.5    8.5     6   (compute (3.5 + 8.5) / 2
5        6     7.5     6    the s_3 tuple 7.5 is ignored because  min_timestamp(7.5) <= max_timestamp(6)
```

While I was able to get this to work with Apache Storm I could not figure out how to do it with Spark because the joining s_2 and s_3 is not allowed in Spark due to different sliding intervals.

So question #1 is: How can I implement this in Spark Streaming?

And question #2: Can you think of any better approach to compute sliding averages over long periods of time efficiently inside the stream processing system?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of strategies for producing approximate answers on streams with pretty high accuracy. One strategy we use is [stratified sampling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYRUYJYOpG0) on infinite streams in spark. 
We introduced Stratified sampling into Apache Spark in an open source project called [SnappyData](http://www.snappydata.io/). Well, among several other things missing in Spark.  SnappyData can maintain uniform random samples on streams but ensures high accuracy by allowing the developer to choose the columns/dimensions that are important in the stream. So, for instance, ensuring that enough samples are captured every minute or each hour, in your example. The samples are visible as Spark Dataframe/Column table and queriable. When aggregate queries like avg/sum/count/etc are executed it uses a bunch of algorithms to compute an answer using a fraction of the resources and time.

Here is pseudo code for how this would look like in Snappydata.

```
Create sample table MyInfiniteStream on <Stream> options (qcs 'min(timestamp), fraction '0.01')
    // Of course, you can use the Dataframe api to do this instead of SQL too. 
    // your DStream <Stream> is registered with SnappyData
    // min(timestamp) tells which columns to use for stratification
    // fraction indicates what percentage of the input data to retain in the sample.
```

Then, you can directly run Spark SQL queries on this with or without error constraints. The nice thing now is that your time interval can be quite granular or coarse.

```
select avg(myMeasureColumn), dimension d from MyInfiniteStream group by d with Error 0.1
// this would ensure the result is always at least 90% accurate. 
select avg(myMeasureColumn), dimension d from MyInfiniteStream where timestamp >x and timestamp < y group by d with Error 0.1
```

You can get a better sense for the ideas [here](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/aqp/). SnappyData is fully compatible with Spark.

You can also try implementing directly in Spark though there is no provision to do online sampling (i.e. on the stream directly) nor built-in algorithms to compute errors with confidence intervals. Checkout the 'sample' methods on Dataset.

Comment: In addition to above, the window for sampling (after which current set is flushed) can be controlled with the timeInterval option in "create sample table" e.g. options (qcs '...', fraction '0.01', timeInterval '120s'). There is also explicit support for timestamp column that can be used instead of wall clock for timeIntervals. This can be set with "timeSeriesColumn '<column>'" option to "create sample table" which should be a timestamp or date type. Then you can keep the "qcs" to be the set of columns on which you intend to group/filter for better accuracy.